# Ink Contract's nonce doesn't increase on internal transaction

Tags: ink, smart-contract, nonce

I have two contracts; `adder` and `accumulator`.
An `inc` method on the `adder` contract internally calls a method on the `accumulator` contract to increase the accumulator's value by 1.

Using my wallet on polkadot.js app, I called the `inc` function on adder contract. After the transaction got included in a block, I can see that the `accumulator` contract's state gets updated, and the nonce on my wallet address increases by 1. However, the nonce on the adder contract still reads `0`.

Shouldn't the `adder` contract's nonce increase by 1 too ( like on EVM ), since it executed a transaction to call the `accumulator` contract?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, nonce update when transaction creates between two different account (i.e. `External Transaction`). When contract invokes function of another contract then it is considered as `Internal Transaction`, hence nonce of contract doesn't update. Contract nonce update when contract create another contract.

[The Transaction Nonce](https://github.com/ethereumbook/ethereumbook/blob/develop/06transactions.asciidoc#the-transaction-nonce)

Comment: Well in Ethereum, the transaction nonce updates when a contract instantiates another contract.

However, on ink, the nonce of a contract stays at zero even if instantiates another contract.